# mecurial on windows error abort: invalid arguement over vpn

Tags: windows, version-control, vpn, tortoisehg

All,

I'm running windows 7 64 bit, latest version of TortoiseHg 64 bit, and the latest version of mecurial 64 bit is installed on windows server 2008. When I try to push my changes to the server, I get the following error:

c:\hg\staged>hg push staged
pushing to \MyServer\hg\staging
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: Invalid argument
c:\hg\staged>

This only happens over vpn and not when I am in office.

If I keep trying to push over vpn I eventually get it to commit but it normally takes me 3 to 4 times.

Does anyone know why this happens over vpn and how I can get around it?

thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to stop directly using TortoiseHg over vpn trying to commit to a mecurial repository on a shared network folder. It was just to slow and errored out. Instead, I connect to vpn, then remote desktop to a computer on the internal network that has visual studio on it and TortoiseHg and use this computer. This way I am directly on a pc within the internal network and now I have no problems or errors using TortoiseHg  or mecurial. In short - TortoiseHg  and mecurial for windows doesn't seem to work well directly over vpn. If you google you will find a few other posts stating this too.